# Does c standard guarantee bit pattern interpretation for signed and unsigned?

Tags: c, bit, standards, signed, representation

Does the C standard state how bit representations should be interpreted? In other words do the following if conditions always evaluate to true? Assume sizeof (int) = 4 and CHAR_BIT = 8

```
unsigned u = 0xffffffff;
if (u == 4294967295) /* do something */

int i = 0xffffffff;
if (i == -1) /* do something */

unsigned u = (int)0xffffffff;
if (u == 0xffffffff) /* do something */

int i = hex_literal;
unsigned u;
memcpy (&u, &i, sizeof (u));
if (i == u) /* do something */
if ((i & 0x7fffffff) == (u & 0x7fffffff)) /* do something */

int i = hex_literal;
unsigned u = i;
if (i == u) /* do something */

unsigned u = hex_literal;
int i = u;
if (i == u) /* do something */

int i = hex_literal;
unsigned u = hex_literal;
if (i == hex_literal && u == hex_literal) /* do something */

char c = 0xff;
if (c >> 4 == 0xf) /* do something */

signed char c = 0xff;
if (((c >> 4) & 0xff) == 0xf) /* do something */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will make the added assumption that no types have padding bits on the implementation under discussion.  Let's take them one at a time:

```
unsigned u = 0xffffffff;
if (u == 4294967295) /* do something */
```

Yes.

```
int i = 0xffffffff;
if (i == -1) /* do something */
```

No.  Conversion of an out-of-range number to a signed type gives an implementation-defined result.

```
unsigned u = (int)0xffffffff;
if (u == 0xffffffff) /* do something */
```

No, same reason as the previous example.

```
int i = hex_literal;
unsigned u;
memcpy (&u, &i, sizeof (u));
if (i == u) /* do something */
if ((i & 0x7fffffff) == (u & 0x7fffffff)) /* do something */
```

Yes.  The standard guarantees that each value bit in a signed type has the same value in the object representation of the corresponding unsigned type.

```
int i = hex_literal;
unsigned u = i;
if (i == u) /* do something */
```

Yes.  The promotion of `i` from `int` to `unsigned` is deterministic and produces the same value both in the assignment to `u` and in the comparison.

```
unsigned u = hex_literal;
int i = u;
if (i == u) /* do something */
```

Yes, but only if `hex_literal` is in the range of (positive) values representable by an `int` - otherwise the implementation-defined result strikes again.

```
int i = hex_literal;
unsigned u = hex_literal;
if (i == hex_literal && u == hex_literal) /* do something */
```

`u == hex_literal` will always evalulate to true, but `i == hex_literal` need only do so if `hex_literal` is in the range of values representable by an `int`.

```
char c = 0xff;
if (c >> 4 == 0xf) /* do something */
```

`char` may be signed or unsigned.  If it is unsigned then the test will be true; if signed, then `c` and `c >> 4` will have implementation-defined values, so it may not be true.

```
signed char c = 0xff;
if (((c >> 4) & 0xff) == 0xf) /* do something */
```

`c` will have an implementation-defined value, so the test may not be true.

Note that all of your questions other than the `memcpy()` one pertain only to the *values* rather than the *representation*.

Answer (score 2):

For unsigned, yes.  For signed types, no; the standard permits 2's complement, 1's complement or sign-magnitude representations.  The relevant section of the standard (C99) is 6.2.6.2.

A separate issue is that code such as `unsigned u = (int)0xffffffff` invokes undefined behaviour, as this causes an integer overflow (section 6.3.1.3).

Yet another issue is that code such as `char c = 0xff; c >> 4` is implementation-defined for two reasons.  Firstly, `char` can either be `signed` or `unsigned`.  Secondly, if it's `signed`, then right-shifting a negative number is implementation-defined (section 6.5.7).

Answer (score 1):

Unsigned numbers have guaranteed modulo 2^n arithmetic. There is no such guarantee for signed ones.

Nothing is said about bit patterns. Note that 0xfffffff is not a "bit pattern", it is a number (whose "bit patterns" have no meaning for the C++ standard) which is guaranteed to satisfy x + 1 = 0 if `x` is an 32 bit unsigned number to which you assigned 0xffffffff.

Comment: It is defined to consist of bits, and the bitwise operators are defined in terms of those bits (well, except that left shift is defined numerically). So all that's in doubt is whether it's a "pattern" -- if so then it's a bit pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Key item to memorize is that hex literals (e.g. `0x0F`) refer to the **value** (here: `15`), not the order in which bits and bytes are stored physically.

It is machine dependant how this is stored - some will store the least significant bit first, others the high bit first, and AFAIK on x86 it's least significant *byte* first but high *bit* first.

But it is always true, that `0x000F` equals `15`.

Comment: Define "first" in the context of bits!

Comment: Let's say bit #0 (2^0) - but I'm not sure at this moment as this is far too long in the past. I just wanted to point out that not all architectures use the same order.

Comment: *G* makes no sense 2^0 *is* the Least significant one :-)

Comment: My point was that order of bits only makes sense if you're sending them on e.g. a serial bus.  If they're just sitting in memory, there is no "first" and "last".